# Is INImage or INImageNoteContent at fault?

Tags: swift, uiimage, sirikit

In working with SiriKit's Notes & Lists domain, I've been able to create `INNote` as a response with `INTextNoteContent`, so the intent and response is working in principle.

For responding with an image, using this code:

```
let image: UIImage? = ...grabbing valid image from app's user data

if let image = image,
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
    let imageNote = INImageNoteContent(image: INImage(imageData: data))
    ...append to [INNote], etc...
}
```

The properties seem to have data, but the intent does not process (Siri speaks, "You may find that information in MyApp"), whereas it displays proper data with just text content. Any ideas on which part I am messing up? Has anyone been successful with `INImageNoteContent`?

Thank you!

Edit: With further experiments, confirmed that `INImage(named: "some image name")` works properly with the `INNote`, which means the implementation of `INImageNoteContent` is bueno, and the focus is on `INImage(imageData: Data)`. Then tried

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "some image name"),
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
    let imageNote = INImageNoteContent(image: INImage(imageData: data))
    ...append to [INNote], etc...
}
```

and

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "some image name"),
    let data = image.cgImage?.dataProvider?.data as Data? {
    let imageNote = INImageNoteContent(image: INImage(imageData: data))
    ...append to [INNote], etc...
}
```

and each produced same results as initial code. Is there any conclusion to draw other than `INImage(imageData: Data)` isn't behaving as advertised?

**Edit**: As of iOS 12, whatever ver is available today, INImage works as intended. I didn't need any code changes, so I'm guessing bug reporting worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that it can be marked as answered rather than left open...

```
let image: UIImage? = ...grabbing valid image from app's user data

if let image = image,
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
    let imageNote = INImageNoteContent(image: INImage(imageData: data))
    ...append to [INNote], etc...
}
```